# Generating bitcoin key pair in python 3.6 from public key to public address

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, cryptography, bitcoin

I have a question about a script I am trying to write that generates a key pair for Bitcoin adreses. I came as far as generating a random private key and generate a public key. I know (or think really much?) that my first part of code is correct. When I go to [bitaddress.org](http://bitaddress.org) and check my generated private keys for details, I always get the correct generated public key.

This is what I have now

```
import os
import ecdsa
import binascii

private_key = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode()
print("private key = " + private_key)

Private_key = bytes.fromhex(private_key)

signing_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(Private_key, curve = ecdsa.SECP256k1)
verifying_key = signing_key.get_verifying_key()

public_key = bytes.fromhex("04") + verifying_key.to_string()
print ("public key = " + public_key.hex())
```

The problem is that for now Im getting the 130 characters public key and I want to transform this to a bitcoin address. I don't understand how to do this. I need to do some encoding/decoding but can't wrap my head around it.
This is the explanation from the internet I found but fail to understand:

[Bitcoin address explanation png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaf6A.png)

Could someone maybe help me with this

Comment: Excuse me for asking; I forgot to add the code I have so far to the question but updated it. I am a novice "developer" and am doing my utterly best to learn about it. I was under the impression that my question was specific. If it is not specific enough please specify.

Comment: which ecdsa module are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am using ecdsa 0.13 (full name says: ecdsa-0.13+26.gc877639-py3.6.egg).

Comment: Ok, so there are 5-10 steps in the procedure outlined. Which one are you stuck at and why?

Comment: Sorry for my stupid questions. I just want to tell you I really really appreciate the fact that you are taking / took time to voluntarily help me on this. I will try to be more specific to not waste your time. As you already noticed I started two weeks ago with coding and spent 10+ hours a day on it. Just love it so far and want to learn all! Trust me that I did really searched:) For my question: I have the pubkey now. I need to perform sha256 hashing but can't find any examples or clear documentation on how to do this in python 3.6. I don't just want to use a ext. lib. since I want to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This code runs both in Python 2 and Python 3.
It prints not only the bitcoin address, but also some intermediate values.
The public key is the 130 hex char string in **pubkey** variable.

Please note that [there are two possible and valid bitcoin addresses for each public key](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Signatures): the uncompressed and the compressed form. Change **compress_key** boolean variable to extract each one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Addresses

import hashlib
import base58

# ECDSA bitcoin Public Key
pubkey = '0450863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b23522cd470243453a299fa9e77237716103abc11a1df38855ed6f2ee187e9c582ba6'
# See 'compressed form' at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Signatures
compress_pubkey = False


def hash160(hex_str):
    sha = hashlib.sha256()
    rip = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    sha.update(hex_str)
    rip.update( sha.digest() )
    print ( "key_hash = \t" + rip.hexdigest() )
    return rip.hexdigest()  # .hexdigest() is hex ASCII


if (compress_pubkey):
    if (ord(bytearray.fromhex(pubkey[-2:])) % 2 == 0):
        pubkey_compressed = '02'
    else:
        pubkey_compressed = '03'
    pubkey_compressed += pubkey[2:66]
    hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey_compressed)
else:
    hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey)

# Obtain key:

key_hash = '00' + hash160(hex_str)

# Obtain signature:

sha = hashlib.sha256()
sha.update( bytearray.fromhex(key_hash) )
checksum = sha.digest()
sha = hashlib.sha256()
sha.update(checksum)
checksum = sha.hexdigest()[0:8]

print ( "checksum = \t" + sha.hexdigest() )
print ( "key_hash + checksum = \t" + key_hash + ' ' + checksum )
print ( "bitcoin address = \t" + base58.b58encode( bytes(bytearray.fromhex(key_hash + checksum)) ) )
```